# Why do I get two different results with minitest assert equal when using a helper function and using string interpolation or concatenation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

** helper method that passes test **

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def full_title(page_title= '')
    base_title = 'Tweeter_clone'
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else 
    page_title + " | " + base_title
    end
  end
end
```

** helper method that does not pass test and returns an empty string "" **

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def full_title(page_title= '')
    base_title = 'Tweeter_clone'
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else 
    `#{page_title} | #{base_title}`
    end
  end
end
```

Below is the actual test. I really don't understand why string interpolation won't work in this case, but concatenation does.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "full title helper" do
      assert_equal 'Tweeter_clone', full_title
    assert_equal "Help | Tweeter_clone", full_title("Help")
  end
end
```

I did include the applicationHelper in test_helper.rb

Comment: Use double quotes " for string interpolation.

Comment: Thanks my mind was in javascript land.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue. Use double quotes in Ruby, and backticks in Javascript.